# MySQL and PHP if/else

Tags: php, mysql

I have a hard time understanding if/else in MySQL. I have a simple Messaging database where I want to delete the message (row), but ONLY if both user deleted it on their end.

So the databate looks like this :

```
----|---------|-------------|------------
mid | message | user1delete | user2delete
----|---------|-------------|------------
 1  |   hi!   |     no      |    yes
----|---------|-------------|------------
```

So I want to look at "mid" 1, if the other user already deleted (hide) the message, delete the row. Else, simply UPDATE "yes" at the right user. Is it possible to do this in one MySQL query, or I must use a PHP if/else statement with multiple queries?

Something that would look lie :

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGES
    IF user1delete = NULL or "no"
        THEN UPDATE user2delete = "yes"
    ELSE IF user1delete = "yes" AND user2delete = "yes"
        THEN DELETE where mid = 1
```

Thank you! (I hope my question is clear...)

**EDIT : I meant to "update" yes...**

Comment: Just select all the rows you want based on the criteria you need (both delete confirmations being 'yes', I assume) and delete them.  It's fairly elementary SQL.

Comment: Not too clear.  Was one of the columns null?  It seems that you'd want something like this:  DELETE FROM table WHERE user1delete = 'yes' and user2delete = 'yes'

Comment: If duplicates are invalid then adding a unique key to the mid, that way you get the error on insert and you can deal with it there.

Comment: by insert he means "update" one of the user*delete columns...
insert -- on duplicate key update is not an option

Comment: Yeah sorry... i meant "update". And I clarified my question... (hoping to...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to delete a row or update the same row in a single query. You can write a stored procedure, if you desperately want to do this in one database call. But keep in mind even if you do it with a single database call to an SP from PHP you are still running multiple queries.

Best solution: Literally deleting data is never good. Create another column for deleted messages and mark them as deleted if both users delete it. This will allow you to keep historical data + you can do your query in one Update statement.

Comment: Thank you. I like the deleted column idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM messages WHERE user1delete="yes" and user2delete="yes";
```

Is that what you are after?

Edit: obviously add into the WHERE statement `mid=1` for just that message

Comment: Thanks, this I can do. But it's the if/else part that tricks me. I could do it in php but I was wondering if it was possible to do it in only one query in MySQL.